# left outer join on the same table with condition

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

I have a table in a mysql 5.7 DB called "mytable" that is made like so:

```
 --------------------
| title   |   flag   |
|--------------------|
| first   |   0      |
| first   |   1      |
| second  |   0      |
 --------------------
```

From this table I need to select only the rows with flag = 0, and from those remove all the ones that has the same title of one with flag = 1. Ending up with a result like this:

```
 --------------------
| title   |   flag   |
|--------------------|
| second  |   0      |
 --------------------
```

How can i write my query? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't expect code to be written for you.

Comment: In my opinion that was a legit question, i was not sure about using "IN" operator, "HAVING COUNT()" or "LEFT OUTER JOIN" so i asked to see the solutions. You don't have to answer if you don't want to...

Comment: This is a faq. As with every question, please google many clear, concise, specific versions/variants/phrasings of your question/problem/goal/desiderata with & without your specific strings/names/code and read many answers from many questions, which should inform your further googling. If you don't find an answer after applying what you learned and repeating this then ask a question. Use the most frequently productive keywords as tags. Use the best search as a title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a sub-query and combine it with MySQL's `IN()` function. The following will work:

```
SELECT title, 
       flag
 FROM mytable
WHERE flag = 0
  AND title NOT IN( SELECT title FROM mytable WHERE flag = 1 );
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d81d7/1)

Comment: upvoted, thanks. unfornately doens't show up because i'm too low on rep. I was guessing if a different solution with something like "having count = 1" could be faster on execution time than using "NOT IN".

Answer (score 0):

Doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT a.*
FROM mytable a
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable b
ON a.title = b.title
AND b.flag = 1
WHERE a.flag = 0
AND b.flag IS NULL
```

Do the LEFT OUTER JOIN, then check for NULL in one of the joined columns to ensure that there is no matching record found.